# Zabbix Trigger overview - not showing OK triggers

Tags: zabbix

*Hello!*

I made a screen and placed a trigger overview resource on it. And right now I don't see a green (OK) triggers, only problems. Before the Zabbix update 4.0.3 it worked well.

[Screenshot of how it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KPLW.png)

Is possible to make it now?

Comment: Did you fully refresh your browser after the update? A ctrl-shift-r on Chrome fully reloads all of the JS and CSV could have changed on the update

Comment: Yes, tried on several browsers and computers. Same thing, OK triggers in Trigger Overview on Screens are not shown, only if they are problem.

Comment: But I didn't reboot server after update, only `systemctl stop zabbix-server` and `systemctl start zabbix-server`. Should I do this?

Comment: [Trigger overview widget settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFmmu.png) Can you verify if there are any alerts at all on the hosts/hosts group selected? Also try setting "Show = Any" instead of Recent Problems/Problems.

Comment: It is not on dashboard, it is on monitoring - screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it happens because of bug. Here is the link to Zabbix bug tracker
https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-15386